# Why is my SQL database sorting by the first column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database where the first column is the weekstart in the UK format (dd/mm/yy).

Each new week a row is added to the table using

```
"INSERT INTO table VALUES (".$weekstart.", 0, 0, 0)";
```

The '0's representing values recorded that week.

As it went into July, 030717 has appeared at the top of the table, rather than appended to the bottom, leading me to assume the table is ordered by the first column. Is there a way to disable this or am I going to have to add an index column?

If I am going to have an index column, what is the best way to do this considering at the start of every new week is when I create the new row in the table - and I don't want to have to do a call to the database to get the previous index just to add one and write to it again?

EDIT:

Query:

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (".$weekStart.", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)";
  runSql($query);

function runSql($query){
  $username = "XXX";
  $password = "XXX";

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=XXX;dbname=XXX', $username, $password);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$read = $stmt->fetchColumn();

return $read;
}
```

As of last week, the column 'weekStart' showed all dates in order (070617, 140617, 210617, 280617). As of this morning, 030717 has pushed itself in the top row.

Comment: Tables are inherently unsorted, the order in which results are displayed is unpredictable, unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause. Also, it looks like you're storing dates in a string column (`varchar`, `char`). You should use a `date` datatype, it's what it's there for. Storing dates as strings gives nothing but headaches.

Comment: I don't have anything (that I can see) that would order the table in this way, any suggestions?

Comment: could you provide the column structure of the table and the query used?

Answer (score 0):

just store date in the column type meant for dates: type DATE

making up a type of yourself will not work, unless you come up with a format that alphabetically would sort in the order you want. But that will leave you without all builtin function to manipulate dates (or datetime if the time has meaning too)